# How to insert mysql data from two source form and other table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table with the following columns:

```
id
bid
name
text
time
```

The `bid` field is comes from another table and the rest are from a `$_POST` form.

Can anyone solve this?

```
$name$_POST['name'];

$text=$_POST['text'];

$time=date(j/F/Y);
```

The SQL queries:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (bid) SELECT bid FROM table2 WHERE id='6'

INSERT INTO table 1 
(name, text, time)
VALUES ($name, $text, $time)
```

I need both of these to happen in one single query.

Comment: Can you show some code? I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Where is the problem and what is to be solved?

Comment: please write some code if you want me to answer ... !

Comment: $name$_POST['name'];
$text=$_POST['text'];
$time=date(j/F/Y);
INSERT INTO table1 (bid) SELECT bid FROM table2 WHERE id='6'

INSERT INTO table 1 
(name, text, time)
VALUES ($name, $text, $time)
I need this at one statement
or one row.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this ::

```
Insert into my_table (id, bid, name, text, time) values (var_id, (Select bid from table_2 where id2=var_id ), var_name, var_text, var_time)
```